# Alert dialog with multiple choice to be checked dynamically android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

My code fetches data from server and made it to display in the alert dialog box with listview, multiple choice option but now, i want every data to be pre checked before loading into listview and mark checked if the condition satisfies is this possible in alert dialog.

//this is my code for loading the value into alertdialog

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Select Category List");

    final ListView modeList = new ListView(getActivity());

                    // Creating a button - Load More
    Button btnDone = new Button(getActivity());
    btnDone.setText("Done");
    btnDone.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(                     android.R.color.white));

    btnDone.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logout_btn);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                            android.R.id.text1, EavesList);
                    modeList.addFooterView(btnDone);

    modeList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
    builder.setView(modeList);
```

My question: Is it possible to check the condition and mark checked before loading multiple choice in alert dialog. if possible, then please respective tutorial or any code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 
[setItemChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) method of ListView for the purpose.

you can use this, after

```
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
```

and put your condition here, and then setItemChecked(position, value); to set the item as checked! if it satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is of type `CharacterSequence[]` or can be converted to one, you can use

```html
AlertDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(CharacterSequence[] list, boolean[] checkedItems, OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)
```

Pass the EavesList as a `CharacterSequence[]` as first parameter, a `boolean[]` specifying which list items are to be checked while creating the Dialog as the second and the listener for when the user toggles the items as the third parameter.